# Text colour based on MySQL data /Temp&Humidity/

Tags: php, text, colors

Home Weather Station, I want to change the text colour based on value.
Link to another similar question: [PHP: Change color of text based on $value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804188/php-change-color-of-text-based-on-value)
Currently, python script takes the data from the DHT22 sensor and saves it into MySQL database.Then simply fetch the last id into PHP.

My goal is to change each result with a separate set of colours e.g.

```
Temperature - 0-15 - blue 
              15.1 - 25 - green
              25.1 - 30 - red

Humidity - 0%-20% - red
           20.1-50 - yellow
           50.1-99 - blue
           99-100 - red
```

Code that I try to understand and implement into my existing code:

```
function getProperColor($number)
{
    if ($var > 0 && $var <= 5)
        return '#00FF00';
    else if ($var >= 6 && $var <= 10)
        return = '#FF8000';
    else if ($var >= 11)
        return = '#FF0000';

<div style="background-color: <?=getProperColor($result['number'])?>;"><?=$result["title"]?></div>
```

This code was provided by @sshow

Unfortunately, I did not succeed with clean code

My Code

```
    <!-- fetchqry taking the result from weather table-->  

  <?php
    
    $fetchqry = "SELECT * 
                 FROM `weather` 
                 order by id 
                 desc 
                 limit 1;"; 
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$fetchqry);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
        $conn->close();
    ?>

    <!-- Printing Temperature & Humidity-->  
    <div><h5><i class="fas fa-temperature-high"></i> Temperature : <font size=6><?php echo $row['temperature']; ?> C°</font></h5></div>
  <div><h5><i class="fas fa-tint"></i> Humidity : <font size=6><?php echo $row['humidity']; ?> %</font></h5></div>
```

Messed up code:

```
<!-- fetchqry1 taking the result from weather table-->
<?php
    
    $fetchqry = "SELECT * 
                 FROM `weather` 
                 order by id 
                 desc 
                 limit 1;"; 
    $result= mysqli_query($conn,$fetchqry);
    $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($num > 0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){ 
 
    function getProperColor($number)
{
    if ($var > 0 && $var <= 5)
        return '#00FF00';
    else if ($var >= 6 && $var <= 10)
        return = '#FF8000';
    else if ($var >= 11)
        return = '#FF0000';
}
    
    $conn->close();
?>

<!-- Printing Temperature & Humidity-->  
<div style="background-color: <?=getProperColor($result['number'])?>;"><?=$result["title"]?><h5><i class="fas fa-temperature-high"></i> Temperature : <font size=6><?php echo $row['temperature']; ?> C°</font></h5></div>
```

This gives me an error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ';' in
> \include\wth_inc.php on line 36

Line 36 is:

```
return = '#FF8000';
```

Thanks

Comment: `=` is an assignment operator. Can you assign something to a `return`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse/syntax errors; and how to solve them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them)

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments:

```
return = '#FF8000';
```

Should be:

```
return '#FF8000';
```

You can also achieve this in the query directly with CASE

```
SELECT *, 
CASE 
    WHEN temperature < 15 THEN '#FF8000'
    WHEN temperature BETWEEN 15 AND 25 THEN '#00FF00'
    WHEN temperature > 25 THEN '#FF0000'
    ELSE '#CCC'
END AS temperature_color,
CASE 
    WHEN humidity < 20 THEN '#FF0000'
    WHEN humidity BETWEEN 20 AND 50 THEN '#00FFFF'
    WHEN humidity BETWEEN 50 AND 99 THEN '#0000FF'
    WHEN humidity > 99 THEN '#FF0000'
    ELSE '#CCC'
END AS humidity_color
                 FROM `weather` 
                 ORDER BY id DESC
                 limit 1
```

Comment: I like the idea using CASE looks a lot easier. With your code Im currently having an error : Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in \include\wth_inc.php on line 40 and line 40 is : $num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

Comment: Can you post the query, seems like it's got an error. Also, I just saw I had an extra comma before FROM delete that and it'll probably work.